# where Should I put index.jsp use tomcat?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I have created a web project using eclipse j2ee,and using tomcat server. In eclipse, when I run servers, the project is running normally. But when I put the project folder into the `/webapps` the tomcat can't find my `index.jsp`, unless I put the index.jsp in the root folder of project.

So,where should I put the `index.jsp` file?

Comment: all jsp filse should come under project_name folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of directly putting the project folder in `/webapps`, create a .WAR file from eclipse and place it in tomcat `/webapps` folder. Tomcat will deploy the application.

Answer (score 0):

If you put your project int the `webapps` folder of a running `tomcat` server you can access it by prefixing the `context path` of your `application`.

Usually the `context path` is named after the application directory. So for example if you put the directory named `app` inside the `webapps` folder of your `tomcat`, and your running a `tomcat` server on your host on the standard `8080` port, you can access it with:

```
http://localhost:8080/app/index.jsp
```

If your're running the `manager` application on your `tomcat` server you can access it and see the list of running application by accessing the url:

```
http://localhost:8080/manager/html/list
```

To access the `manager` application you need to have a valid user in the `tomcat-users.xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

`Eclipse` `WebProject` or `J2EE` project creates a `WebContent` folder which is sibling to `src`.

During deployment to `Tomcat` on any other associated `WebServer`, it creates a `war` webapp folder structure first then copies all `WebContent` folder contents into `webapps` and complie `Java` classes from `src` into `webapps\web-inf\classes`.

What you require is to put `index.jsp` into `WebContent` folder and have required mapping in `web.xml` under `welcome-files` element.

Answer (score 0):

wherever you keep the index.jsp it will not hamper unless you have mentioned correctly in web.xml file.

example suppose your index.jsp is in webapps/project/file then you should write in web.xml in this way

```
    <welcome-file>file/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

suppose it is in another folder webapps/project/file/file1

```
    <welcome-file>file/file1/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

suppose the index.jsp is in webapps/project/index.jsp
then web.xml will be

```
    <welcome-file>/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: thank you,now the index.jsp can run,but the servlet still '404',why...I put servlets in the /src folder